# How to define am nullability constrain for multiple fields in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, constructor, nullable

I have a class Apartment. I need to make all properties nullable per field but not the following three (shareNumber, shareNrFrom, debentureNumber) at the same time. The constraint that I added in the constructor is supposed to do the job, but instead, it fails every time since all the values are null when the check is performed. When I try to debug it and place a breakpoint in the constructor it appears to be that all fields are null, even tho I do provide a couple of them when I instantiate the class.

```
package info
    
import arrow.optics.optics
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty

@optics
@ApiModel(description = "en: Apartment")
data class Apartment(

        @get:ApiModelProperty("en: Name of the Cooperative", required = false)
        val housingCooperative: String? = null,

        @get:ApiModelProperty("en: OrgNr of the Cooperative", required = false)
        val companyOrgNo: String? = null,

        @get:ApiModelProperty("en: shareNumber", required = false)
        val shareNumber: String? = null,

        @get:ApiModelProperty("en: shareNrFrom", required = false)
        val shareNrFrom: String? = null,

        @get:ApiModelProperty("en: debentureNumber", required = false)
        val debentureNumber: String? = null,

) {

    init {
        require(shareNumber!=null || shareNrFrom!=null || debentureNumber!=null) { "shareNumber, shareNrFrom and debentureNumber cannot be nullable at the same time" }
    }

    class Builder internal constructor(
            private var housingCooperative: String? = null,
            private var companyOrgNo: String? = null,
            private var shareNumber: String? = null,
            private var shareNrFrom: String? = null,
            private var debentureNumber: String? = null
    ) {
        fun housingCooperative(housingCooperative: String): Builder = also {this.housingCooperative = housingCooperative}
        fun companyOrgNo(companyOrgNo: String): Builder = also {this.companyOrgNo = companyOrgNo}
        fun shareNumber(shareNumber: String): Builder = also {this.shareNumber = shareNumber}
        fun shareNrFrom(shareNrFrom: String): Builder = also {this.shareNrFrom = shareNrFrom}
        fun debentureNumber(debentureNumber: String): Builder = also {this.debentureNumber = debentureNumber}

        fun build(): Apartment = Apartment(
                housingCooperative = housingCooperative,
                companyOrgNo =       companyOrgNo,
                shareNumber =        shareNumber,
                shareNrFrom =        shareNrFrom,
                debentureNumber =    debentureNumber
            )
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun builder(): Builder = Builder()
    }
}
```

This is how I instantiate the class.

```
apartment = Apartment(
    shareNrFrom = "12",
    debentureNumber = "34"
)
```

Comment: Did you expect the code to fail the `require(...)` call? I expect the opposite - you are expecting at least one property to be non-null, after all. Did you mean to use `&&` instead of `||` perhaps?

Comment: No I expect it not to fail, but it does instead

Comment: How is your object being created? I don't know Arrow, but perhaps it's creating it ‘empty’ and then setting the properties? (In Spring, that couldn't happen for constructor params, but it could happen for autowired properties, and the solution would be to check in a `@PostConstruct` method instead of the constructor/initialiser.)